# Detectar a mudança de resolução da janela

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso que quando o usuario redimensionar a janela, eu consiga detectar para poder mandar a pagina dar um refresh.

Comment: se queres a questão como resolvida, marca uma resposta como correta, não alteres o titulo da pergunta.

Comment: Pegasus, parece que você ainda não sabe [*Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/201)

Answer (score 6):

Em JavaScript temos um manipulador de eventos para o evento de redimensionamento da `window`, o [`window.onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>.

```js
window.onresize = function(){
   location.reload();
};
```

### Mas atenção:

Despoletar uma atualização da página no decorrer da alteração do tamanho da tela é complicado, porque enquanto estamos a alterar o tamanho, a página recarrega, volta a detetar a mudança, volta a recarregar...

A solução passa por garantir que a alteração de tamanho terminou e após isso chamar a atualização:

```js
function recarregarPagina(){
    // Sem redimencionamento à 100ms!
    location.reload();
}

var boraLa;
window.onresize = function(){
  clearTimeout(boraLa);
  boraLa = setTimeout(recarregarPagina, 100);
};
```

Aqui, fazendo uso do [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> e do [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearTimeout) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> estamos a verificar a cada 100 milissegundos se a página ainda está a ser redimensionada. Se já acabou, chamamos a nossa função `recarregarPagina()`.

Enquanto o utilizador estiver a redimensionar a tela, o temporizador está sempre a ser colocado a 0 (zero). Quando o utilizador parar de redimensionar a tela, ao fim de 100 milissegundos a nossa função `recarregarPagina()` é chamada. Dentro da mesma temos o código a executar, no teu caso: `location.reload();`.

Comment: Ótima resposta. Perfeito!

Answer (score 3):

Se você pode usar JQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // código que será executado quando o browser for redimensionado.
});
```

Veja: [JQuery - método .resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Answer (score 0):

```
//recarrega a pagina se mudar a resolução.
$( window ).resize(function() {
  document.location.reload();
});//
```

Comment: Não creio que vai ficar legal dessa maneira. A função pode ser invocada várias vezes enquanto a janela está sendo redimensionada (usuário arranstando a borda do navegador).